# Check how Many mongoose documents exist

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to code a guess the emoji system and for this I need to check how many Models exists.

This is what I'm trying to do:

`const data = model.findOne();`

`model.create({ ID: data.length + 1})`

I try to search for the models and then create a new model with an ID which includes the number of the existing models + 1.

If I run the command with this code, it returns `NaN` in my database at `ID`. So it's "NotANumber".

Does someone know how to fix?

Comment: `model.findOne()` returns the first matching result, so `data` won't have a `.length` as it is at most, a single result.

Answer (score 0):

When you use findOne it returns an object so when you are using Object.length you are getting an error.

Best method

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
// Correct query
// will return number
const count = await model.countDocuments();
```

TBH I didn't understand your project just understood what you want regarding mongoose ORM.